# Cannot get python to follow go in base32 encoding

Tags: python, go, base32

I am trying to replicate a base32 encoding of a sha256 hash from go in python. I am trying to replicate the logic by which kube-router creates ipset names for namespace-networkpolicies: https://github.com/cloudnativelabs/kube-router/blob/736757d942f173e19566eea0a512dfa819699126/pkg/controllers/netpol/network_policy_controller.go#L1476

I just cannot get python to yield the same base32 output. I am probably doing something obviously wrong. Help!

Go Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/base32"
)

func main() {
    namespace := "my-ns"
    policyName := "default-deny"

    chksum := sha256.Sum256([]byte(namespace + policyName))
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", chksum)
    fmt.Println(base32.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(chksum[:]))
    fmt.Println(base32.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte("abc")))
}
```

running this yields:

```
dd684919ef4a1362b841409f5255ec963bd53d353804114779c4e6d66641eb28
3VUESGPPJIJWFOCBICPVEVPMSY55KPJVHACBCR3ZYTTNMZSB5MUA====
MFRGG===
```

Python Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import hashlib
import base64

namespace = "my-ns"
policyName = "default-deny"

sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
sha256.update(namespace+policyName)
chksum = sha256.hexdigest()
print chksum
print base64.b32encode(chksum)
print base64.b32encode(bytearray("abc"))
```

running this yields:

```
dd684919ef4a1362b841409f5255ec963bd53d353804114779c4e6d66641eb28
MRSDMOBUHEYTSZLGGRQTCMZWGJRDQNBRGQYDSZRVGI2TKZLDHE3DGYTEGUZWIMZVGM4DANBRGE2DONZZMM2GKNTEGY3DMNBRMVRDEOA=
MFRGG===
```

The first lines of output in each agree, which is good. lets me know that the sha256 checksum is being computed the same on each side. The second line on each doesn't agree, I do not understand why -- I have tried many different casts of the chksum in the python code to no avail. The third line in each just suggests that a base32 encoding of a simple string seems to work on both sides.

Comment: FYI... there is no need to base64-encode a hash that is in hexadecimal format. Such a character set `[0-9] [a-f]` is safe to send over any protocol.

Comment: thanks for the comment. The original code is kube-router is computing an identifier for use in ipsets in iptables. it is not used to send over any protocol, just to construct a safe identifier to use in the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Python side you're getting the SHA256 hash hex-encoded, and then base32 encoding the hexadecimal digits. To fix it, use the following:

```
sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
sha256.update(namespace+policyName)
chksum = sha256.digest() # Get hash as byte string
print chksum.encode('hex') # Convert byte string to hexadecimal for printing
print base64.b32encode(chksum)
print base64.b32encode(bytearray("abc"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried a bunch of different casts/transforms before putting into base32 encode. I did not try the .encode('hex') -- that was just what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

The go version isn’t base32 encoding the hex version of the digest. It encodes the raw form. You’re printing the hex form differently on each side.

Comment: I have basically no experience with/understanding of go -- certainly contributing to the problem. I read the docs, but am not seeing the problem. Is there a code suggestion for could give to get the python code to yield the same base32 encoding, please?

Comment: cpburnz gave you a direct example but just digest() instead of hexdigest().